# What's a good way to abstract/refactor this switch/case?

Tags: c++, templates, protocol-buffers

In the source code of a project I see a switch/case clause of 300 lines. But it's very well structured, as every single case is just like this:

```
        case X:
        {
            msg_type_for_X msg;

            if (msg.ParseFromArray (m_readBuffer))
                recv_X (msg);
        }
            break;
```

which makes me wish to put this into 20 lines. Here for each case `X`, the class `msg_type_for_X` is a class defined by protobuf. To me it seems tricky as there is no way for the compiler to know what type msg has. So how would people refactor something like this? Or people just leave it alone?

Comment: Please show more of the code, and this question is too ambiguous.

Comment: If all cases are exactly the same, then with a macro

Comment: @OldProgrammer https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple_overlay/impl/PeerImp.h#L853-L1145 I understand that it might be too ambiguous, I just want to see how people would handle a situation like this.

Comment: Ugh.  What a nightmare!

Answer (score 2):

You can use token pasting inside a macro. Look [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator.html).

It will be something like:

```
#define CASE_MSG(X) \
    case X: \
    { \
        msg_type_for_##X msg; \
        if (msg.ParseFromArray (m_readBuffer)) \
            recv_##X (msg); \
    } \
    break;
```

Also there are other ways to do this kind of thing and is having an array of msg_type_for_X structures, you initialize them all, and then you don't even need to use a case:

```
if (messages[X].ParseFromArray(m_readBuffer))
       messages[X].recv(msg);
```

Of course it needs some refactoring to include the `recv_X` as a method of the message parser.

Answer (score 0):

Start with simple base interface like

```
struct IMsgOperation { virtual int indexOf() const = 0; virtual bool ParseFromArray(param of type m_readBuffer) = 0; /*virt desturctor and etc*/}
```

Then define specific class for each X type:

```
struct XMsgOperation : public IMsgOperation { int indexOf() const { return hardcode_index_of_X_from_some_enum; }; virtual bool ParseFromArray(); }
```

and implement it;
Than create array of instances for each XMsgOperation,

```
vector<IMsgOperation *> parsers(num_of_parsers, NULL);
```

Than fill array

```
IMsgOperation *pOp=new FooMsgOperation; parsers[pOp->indexOf()]=pOp; ...
```

and invent mapping function to map each value of X to proper index

```
static int IMsgOperation::type2index(type_of_X X) { switch(X) { case X: return 0; ...} }
```

Than it can be used:

```
parsers[IMsgOperation::type2index(type_of_X X)]->ParseFromArray(m_readBuffer)
```

Note if type_of_X is kind of integer then you can organize values of type_of_X as linear sequense and eliminate type2index. Above does not contain any safe checks, add them on your oun taste.